# Solutions of $x^3+y^3+z^3=42$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> I was surfing through youtube and found this amazing question on diophantine equation. If $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $$x^3+y^3+z^3=42$$ find the values of $(x,y,z)$.

I tried this equation to do by myself. All in vain. Then I decided to use softwares. All in vain. One software declared that there are no integer solutions. Even wolframalpha was not able to found the solutions.

Is there really any solution$?$ If yes how do we find it$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes) for details.

Comment: The phrasing of the question suggests that there is a unique solution. Of course that's not true because any permutation of a solution $(x,y,z)$ yields another solution, but heuristically it also seems likely that there are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$(-80538738812075974)^3 + 80435758145817515^3 + 12602123297335631^3 = 42$$ This was found by Andrew Booker and Andrew Sutherland using a computer search.

Comment: Here are some [more details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes#Computational_results)

Comment: Is this the smallest combination of values that satisfies the equation?

Comment: According to the original paper [ON A QUESTION OF MORDELL](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.01209.pdf), p.2: "An attractive feature of this algorithm is that it
finds all solutions with $\min\{|x|, |y|, |z|\} \leq B$, even those for which $\max\{|x|, |y|, |z|\}$ may be much larger than $B$." So (unless hard- or software errors occurred) it is the smallest solution in the sense that no other solution has one of $x, y, z$ smaller in absolute value than the smallest magnitude of the presented solution triple.